# Can I create a Custom "Taskbar" in Ubuntu Unity

Tags: 12.04, unity, themes, taskbar, menu-bar

As the title says, I am creating a theme for my Ubuntu 12.04 Unity session creation in progress for a buddy of mine. I would like to add an image on the lower portion of my screen.

I have taken the requested taskbar and made a taskbar.png file that I wish to add as the taskbar with buttons that perform commands when pressed. Am I expecting to much as in simplicity or would I have to do major programming?

I have seen something that is similar to what i wish to do, using tint2 for a taskbar, this might be simpler if theres a way to edit this with its own theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way, using the latest version of Wine, I can install Rainmeter, a better Windows Conky Alternative, and do everything I wish to do. Its easier to program (since I'm used to the program on my other PCs). Unfortunately if you wish to copy my work, at the current time you can only install Rainmeter 1.3 or lower, anything higher will crash as you attempt to open the program (may work differently on your installation). Also transparency's do not work, they appear black. Not much of a problem for me.